Springboot application Not Retrieving" data from my database and not showing in my console
Whenever I attempt to input user details in my browser and view the outcome in my console to retrieve what I entered, it fails to display. Even when I attempted the process using the H2 console with a different project, it also failed to work. I suspect it may be related to my IDE or Java version.
and In my view file, everything appears to be correctly implemented, and both the key and the value seem accurate.
if you want more detail of code snippets I can provide but also
For those who want to view whole minor project here is the giuthub link
https://github.com/vb51/Insurance_Report_Project.git
This is my repo class
public interface Citizenplanrepo extends JpaRepository<CitizenPlan, Integer> {
  // retrieve data for drop-down display

         @Query("select distinct(planName) from CitizenPlan")
         public List<String> getPlanNames();
    
         @Query("select distinct(planStatus) from CitizenPlan")
        public List<String> getPlanStatus();
    
    
}

Service class

@Service
public class CitizenPlanServiceImpl implements CitizenPlanService {

    
    @Autowired
    private Citizenplanrepo repo;
    
    @Override
    public List<String> getPlanNames() {
        return repo.getPlanNames();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getPlanStatus() {
        return repo.getPlanStatus();
    }

    @Override
    public List<CitizenPlan> Searchcitizen(SearchCriteria sc) {
        return  repo.findAll();
    
    }

    @Override
    public void generateExcel(HttpServletResponse response) {
    

    }

    @Override
    public void generatePdf(HttpServletResponse response) {
        

    }

}

controller class
@Controller
public class CitizenController {
    
    @Autowired
private CitizenPlanService service; 
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String indexModel(Model model) {
         List<String> planNames = service.getPlanNames();
         
         List<String> planStatus= service.getPlanStatus();
         
         model.addAttribute("planNames",planNames);
    
         model.addAttribute("planStatus",planStatus);
         
         model.addAttribute("search",new SearchCriteria());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/filter-data")
    public String handleSearchbtn(@ModelAttribute("search") SearchCriteria criteria, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println(criteria);       
        
        List<CitizenPlan> citizensInfo = service.Searchcitizen(criteria);
        
        model.addAttribute("Citizen",citizensInfo);
        
        
        
        List<String> planNames = service.getPlanNames();
         
         List<String> planStatus= service.getPlanStatus();
         
         model.addAttribute("planNames",planNames);
    
         model.addAttribute("planStatus",planStatus);
         
        return "index";
            
    }

This is the output  showing in console while user input's data in my view file
com.vishwas.binding.SearchCriteria@1547dbee
Hibernate: select distinct cp1_0.plan_name from citizen_plan cp1_0
Hibernate: select distinct cp1_0.plan_status from citizen_plan cp1_0


Please provide the relevant code into the question we aren't going to review all the code in your github repository

Please go through this to understand the right approach to post a question on Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
The question you have posted does not have enough information for anybody to answer and it does not show what you have attempted to address your problem

kindly check it

Also I can advice you put more debug output everywhere to understand what happens, particularly in service impl
